# Failed to build DAWG issue

Tags: build, dawg

Im trying to install a package, but one of its dependencies is DAWG and it just cant install it correctly. The only solution ive found is downgrading to python 3.8 where it works, but I dont want to depend on that.
The error in mention is:

```
  Running setup.py clean for DAWG
Failed to build DAWG
ERROR: Could not build wheels for DAWG, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried installing it from pip, conda, and it just doesnt work with python 11.